# Is it safe to manually edit /etc/passwd?

Tags: ubuntu, passwd

I need to change the "real name" of a user (not the username).
For example if I have:

```
testuser:x:1001:1001:Max Mustermann,,,:/home/testuser:/bin/bash
```

And I want it to be:

```
testuser:x:1001:1001:Max Müller,,,:/home/testuser:/bin/bash
```

Can I just edit it manually or will that negatively effect anything (for example ssmtp)? I know that the username can be changed safely using `usermod`, but I never had to change the "real" name before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the "username" (actually GECOS/comment) field with the `usermod -c` command

Comment: The manpage of <code>usermod</code> isn't very clear on that one, thank you, it worked as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than editing the password file directly it is recommended to use [**`vipw`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw) which will set the appropriate locks to prevent file corruption.

But to change the display name (and other GECOS info) both a user and root can also use the [**`chfn`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chfn) command.

Other than that, go ahead!